# R data.table: Merge conditional summary of a data.table back to the original data.table in one statement

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following dummy data -

```
dummyData = data.table(A = c(2,2,2,3,4,2,3,2,4,3), B = c(1.2, 3.2, 4.3, 3.1, 5.4, 6.6, 3.5, 3.2, 4.2, 2.3), desired_Result = c(18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5))
```

I want to add a new column to this data.table as follows -
Pick the values in column B where A == 2, then add these values and make a new column C in original data.table

I do not want the sum of B based on group A, but the result should have only the sum of column B where A == 2. Following is the code I tried, but it is giving me summarized data.table

```
dummyData[, actual_Result := sum(B), by = A]
```

Following should be the output

```
    A   B desired_Result actual_Result
 1: 2 1.2           18.5          18.5
 2: 2 3.2           18.5          18.5
 3: 2 4.3           18.5          18.5
 4: 3 3.1           18.5          18.5
 5: 4 5.4           18.5          18.5
 6: 2 6.6           18.5          18.5
 7: 3 3.5           18.5          18.5
 8: 2 3.2           18.5          18.5
 9: 4 4.2           18.5          18.5
10: 3 2.3           18.5          18.5
```

Following code gives NA in rows where A is 3 or 4, I need all the rows in actual_Result to have value 18.5

```
dummyData[A == 2, actual_Result := sum(B), by = A]

    A   B desired_Result actual_Result    C
 1: 2 1.2           18.5          18.5 18.5
 2: 2 3.2           18.5          18.5 18.5
 3: 2 4.3           18.5          18.5 18.5
 4: 3 3.1           18.5           8.9   NA
 5: 4 5.4           18.5           9.6   NA
 6: 2 6.6           18.5          18.5 18.5
 7: 3 3.5           18.5           8.9   NA
 8: 2 3.2           18.5          18.5 18.5
 9: 4 4.2           18.5           9.6   NA
10: 3 2.3           18.5           8.9   NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
library(data.table)
dummyData[, actual_Result := sum(B[A == 2])]

dummyData
#    A   B desired_Result actual_Result
# 1: 2 1.2           18.5          18.5
# 2: 2 3.2           18.5          18.5
# 3: 2 4.3           18.5          18.5
# 4: 3 3.1           18.5          18.5
# 5: 4 5.4           18.5          18.5
# 6: 2 6.6           18.5          18.5
# 7: 3 3.5           18.5          18.5
# 8: 2 3.2           18.5          18.5
# 9: 4 4.2           18.5          18.5
#10: 3 2.3           18.5          18.5
```

which using base R is

```
dummyData$actual_Result <- sum(dummyData$B[dummyData$A == 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, we can use

```
library(dplyr)
dummyData %>%
    mutate(actual_Result = sum(B[A ==2]))
```